# Select by attributes returning wrong records

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, select-by-attribute

I'm trying to select by attributes on a parcel shapefile with 555k+ records using the apn field and the statement is returning records that have completely different values. My initial statement was `"apn" = '525-670-10-2'`

And received the top two records with APNs starting with 84A.

Then I tried a wild card and got a whole slew of records starting with 84A:

[image]

Has anyone encountered this and was able to correct it? I'm using ArcMap 10.6

Comment: try copying an apn cell and paste it to notepad.  Does it match?  Also this may be pointless but have you tried "apn" like '525%670%'?  Does it always return the 84A-...?  If you do a ctrl+f and search the apn column for 525-670-10-2, do you get a match?

Comment: also what is the datatype of the apn column?

Comment: Maybe rename your Shapefile to something simple and short, it is a bit long with dashes and underscores.

Comment: I second klewis. Naming shapefile like this is bad idea.

Comment: You could try generating a shapefile with 555K+ records - half with this problematic value and half with another then see if that gives the right result.  If not, do the same in a file geodatabase feature class and try again.